# How to navigate to a link using page object gem?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, page-object-gem

How to navigate to a page using page-object gem when am calling in a method?

```rb
class SidePage
 include PageObject

link(:create, text: /Create/)

def navigate_to(link)
  if link == 'Test'
    create
  else
    navigate_to "http://test.jprr.w3test/#{link}" # --> here i need to navigate on else condition.
  end
end
```

I need to navigate to the given link dynamically in else condition based on the #{link} text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `#navigate_to` within `#navigate_to` as it will go into an infinite loop. There are a couple ways to solve this.

The easiest approach is to name your method differently. Part of the benefit is that it's clear that this page's `#navigate_to` is different than other pages.

```
def navigate_or_click(link)
    if link == 'Test'
        create
    else
        navigate_to "http://test.jprr.w3test/#{link}"
    end
end
```

If you want to stick with the `#navigate_to` method name, you just need to call the appropriate browser method instead:

```
def navigate_or_click(link)
    if link == 'Test'
        create
    else
        browser.goto "http://test.jprr.w3test/#{link}" # or platform.navigate_to
    end
end
```